# How Do I Playing An Audio File In Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, audio, android-mediaplayer

Ok So I have about 30 Audio Files In Sequence Say,

```
Audio1
Audio2
Audio3
Audio4
...
```

I have 3 EditText With Hints ,"From","To" and "How Many Times To Play?" and One Button

The User needs to enter in "From" the number of starting audio file say 5 and in "To" the number of ending audio file (Say 9) and in "How Many Times To Play" the number of times these audios need to be played in sequence (say 10).

When The User Clicks The Button It Should Play From Audio5 to Audio9 in sequence.When It Finishes Audio9,It Should Wait For Say About 2 seconds and then again start from Audio5 to Audio9 and then the same process till it plays them 10 times (in sequence) as the user entered 10 in "How Many Times To Play". How Can I Achieve This?Please Help!

Also One More Question,Is There Any Way To Create Multiple "raw" folders,to categorize different types of audios?

Answer (score 0):

put all resource ids in an array
create three ints one for "from" one for "to" one for "currentlyplaying"
currentlyplaying = from;

onclick(play button)

while currently <= to
 play currentlyplaying
 currentlyplaying++;

the while loop inside another while loop
 i = 0;
 while 0 < numberOfIterations

do above code

sloppy reply but I hope it helped. Provide some code and I'll try to help write. I think there is but you may have to specify a subfolder down the line.